# How to turn this recursive function into a list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I've made a function that interchanges the elements of two lists in turn and it works recursively.

```
change :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
change [] ys = ys
change xs [] = xs
change (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : change xs ys
```

Now this works fine but I am having difficulty with turning it into list comprehension. I want to do that to practice Haskell and it was just one of the questions I found.

Comment: I don't think you *can* do this with a list comprehension: the list comprehension can add only a single value to the list at one time.

Comment: If you could somehow nest a bunch of list comprehensions together, the result would certainly have to be less elegant than the code already shown.

Comment: As an aside, you have one more base case than you need: `change [] ys = ys; change (x:xs) ys = x : change ys xs`. (Here, you add only a single value at a time, but alternate which list you pull from *during* the iteration, something else a list comprehension can't do to the best of my knowledge.)

Comment: In case both lists have the same length you could do something like `change' xs ys  = [a | (u, v) <- zip xs ys, a <- [u, v]]`, and I'm sure you could extend it to the unequal length case while still technically havining a comprehension, but as has already been mentioned it would be quite inelegant.

Comment: I think `change xs ys = concat $ transpose [xs, ys]`...

Comment: @flawr there's a ghc extension for that :) ParallelListComprehensions

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
change xs ys = [v | vs <- transpose [xs, ys], v <- vs]
```

But I wouldn't. That's a very confusing way to write this function -- and anyway, you haven't really converted manual recursion into a list comprehension this way, you've just shoved the manual recursion into `transpose`.